# Select rows where particular records are removed based on another table

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access

I have the following table A:

```
Cell1 Time1
a1    t1
a1    t2
```

And another table B:

```
Cell2 Time2 SomeColumn2
a1    t1    c1
a1    t3    c2
```

I want values from table B where (Cell2,Time2) combination is not in Table A as (Cell1,Time1).

e.g in the given case the output would be :

```
Cell2 Time2 SomeColumn2
a1    t3    c2
```

What would be the solution in TSQL or ms-access sql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.*
FROM TableB b
LEFT JOIN TableA a ON b.Cell2=a.Cell1 AND b.Time2=A.Time1
WHERE a.Cell1 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from TableB as TB
where not exists(select *
                 from TableA as TA
                 where TB.Cell2 = TA.Cell1 and
                       TB.Time2 = TA.Time1)
```

Not tested in Microsoft Access.

Answer (score 0):

The relational operator you require is [antijoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29).

SQL lacks an explicit antijoin operator or `JOIN` type or keyword; the same applies to Access (ACE, Jet, whatever). Note the truly relational language [Tutorial D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28data_language_specification%29) uses `NOT MATCHING` for its antijoin operator, for example.

An antijoin can of course be written using other SQL operators. The most commonly seen use `EXISTS` or `IN (subquery)`. Depending on the data, it may be possible to use an outer join with a restriction on a key from the outer table testing for null.

Personally, I prefer to use EXISTS in SQL for antijoin because the join clauses are closer together in the written code and doesn't result in projection over the joined table. This is the approach used in @Mikael Eriksson's answer.

Comment: I find these answers and comments of yours referring to non-applicable relational theories to be worse than useless. I wish you'd not bother.

Comment: David-W-Fenton: I no doubt come across as a bore with such writings (though generally the votes I've received have been up :) Personally, I'm finding it valueable to be able to identify the relational operators behind the SQL constructs. I admit I considered this kind of thing irrelevant until relatively recently. Sincere apologies in advance because you can expect more of the same.